# OSX Alert while running a background task

Tags: macos, cocoa, alert

Disclaimer: I am a beginner when it comes to OSX development.

I have a method named "checkUser". Inside that method, I need to check if the entered user credentials are valid. To check if the credentials are valid, I need to call a method named "methodThatInvolvesNetwork", where its execution time may vary since it involves a network connection. In "checkUser", I need to display an alert that shows progress while "methodThatInvolvesNetwork" is running. The user can also cancel the alert, which will also cancel the running "methodThatInvolvesNetwork".
Q1) How should I go about this?

Note that it is a must that "checkUser"'s execution is blocked, and the "methodThatInvolvesNetwork" is called within "checkUser".

I currently have this implementation:

```
- (BOOL)checkUser
{
    NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"Sample" defaultButton:@"Okay" alternateButton:nil otherButton:nil informativeTextWithFormat:@""];
    self.alert = alert;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        [self methodThatInvolvesNetwork];
    });

    [alert runModal];
    NSLog(@"After run modal");
}

- (void)methodThatInvolvesNetwork
{
    // Do long running task here.

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if (self.alert != nil)
        {
            [[self.alert window] orderOut:self.alert];
            [[NSApplication sharedApplication] stopModal];
        }
    });
}
```

Q2) Is my implementation above the right way to go about it?
Q3) If yes, then why does NSLog(@"After run modal") get executed long after the modal alert has been dismissed, not immediately after the modal alert has been dismissed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, this is what I have used which met the requirements:

- An NSWindow with an NSWindowController.
  This window will run "methodThatInvolvesNetwork" in the background on load of the window.
- Inside "checkUser", I instantiated the window above, "myWindow", and then passed it to:
- Geowar's answer above (but with no didEndSelector):

  `[NSApp beginSheetModalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:]`
- After the line above, I run it as modal using:

  `[NSApp runModalForWindow:myWindow];`

  so that the execution of "checkUser" is blocked.
- When "myWindow" is finished (when stopModal or abortModal is called), then the execution of "checkUser" will continue.

Answer (score 0):

[alert runModal] won't return until the alert is dismissed. If there's a window that you can attach it to as a sheet then you should be able to use beginSheetModalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo: which will callback the selector when the alert is closed (and not block).

Comment: I need the alert to be blocking, so that the "checkUser"'s return value is based on "methodThatInvolvesNetwork".